# Could not import 'backend.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. AttributeError: Type "Mutation" not found in the Schema

Tags: python, django

Im trying to merge two GraphQL outputs and I have this error when I try to load

Could not import 'backend.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. AttributeError: Type "Mutation" not found in the Schema.

I have two schemas within each corresponding apps

```py
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from careers import models
import graphene

class JobType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Job

class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Category

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_jobs = graphene.List(JobType)
    job_by_slug = graphene.Field(CategoryType, slug=graphene.String())

    def resolve_jobs_by_category(root, info, category):
        return (
            models.Job.objects.prefetch_related("category")
            .select_related("title")
            .filter(category__name__iexact=category)
        )
    
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

and the 2nd on here:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from blog import models
import graphene


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()


class AuthorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile


class PostType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post


class TagType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Tag


class ImageType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UploadImage


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_posts = graphene.List(PostType)
    author_by_username = graphene.Field(AuthorType, username=graphene.String())
    post_by_slug = graphene.Field(PostType, slug=graphene.String())
    posts_by_author = graphene.List(PostType, username=graphene.String())
    posts_bt_tag = graphene.List(PostType, tag=graphene.String())

    def resolve_all_posts(root, info):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags").select_related("author").all()
        )

    def resolve_author_by_username(root, info, username):
        return models.Profile.objects.select_related("user").get(
            user__username=username
        )

    def resolve_image(self, info):
        if self.image:
            self.image = info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.image_url)
        return self.image

    def resolve_post_by_slug(root, info, slug):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .get(slug=slug)
        )

    def resolve_posts_by_author(root, info, username):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .filter(author__user__username=username)
        )

    def resolve_posts_bt_tag(root, info, tag):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .filter(tags__name__iexact=tag)
        )


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

and then I have a third schema in the main app which looks like so:

```py
import graphene

import blog.schema as first_app
import careers.schema as second_app

class Query(first_app.schema.Query, second_app.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    # Inherits all classes and methods from app-specific queries, so no need
    # to include additional code here.
    pass

class Mutation(first_app.schema.Mutation, second_app.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    # Inherits all classes and methods from app-specific mutations, so no need
    # to include additional code here.
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Then when I try to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql I get the error above.